# Azure Service Bus Topic Subscription

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have a topic that has multiple subscriptions. When one of the subscription fails the message is moved to the DLQ. Is there a way to find out which subscription failed? and if the same message is processed again then how to make sure that the subscriptions that have already processed the message do not process it again?

Comment: Each subscription gets their own DLQ.

Answer (score 0):

In topic subscription if there are n numbers of subscription and when message is sent to the topic then each message is sent to the individual subscription. Depending on the filter condition the subscription will either accept or discard the message. Each subscription will have their own dead letter so you can read the messages from the individual subscription dead letter.